# Specify the Source of an Image

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I had the following very simple code that, of course, worked :

```
<Image Source="Resources\data_store.png"/>
```

The thing is that I now have to take the string from the property ("name") of an object that is given as an ItemSource and I dont manage to get bind to it

I tried these but none work :

```
<Image Source=name/>
<Image Source=Path="name"/>
<Image Source=Path=name/>
<Image Source={Path="name"}/>
<Image Source={Path=name}/>
<Image Source={Binding name}/>
```

My object is set in the c# codebehind and I don't think it changes something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code behind, make sure you define the source as Property:

```
public string Name{get;set;}
```

then the binding works as follows:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
```

If you want to dynamically update the image, you will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and invoke PropertyChanged when the image is changed

Comment: At least in Silverlight, this does work, since the binding engine is able to convert a string into an URI

Comment: It seems to work but I ain't got any Image. My feeling is that your code is right but my strings are like "Resources\\data_store.png", with a double / and I feel like this is what fail at the convertion, am I right ?

Comment: Does the Output Window say anything?

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IconPath' property not found on 'object' ''Image' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=IconPath; DataItem='Image' (Name=''); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource') ### My "name" is IconPath

Comment: So, of course, I used : <Image Source="{Binding IconPath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>

Comment: RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} refers to the element on which you are setting the binding, in this case the Image element...so it is looking for IconPath property on the Image class. Try setting the DatatConext to the data object and removing the RelativeSource from the binding.

Comment: Right... I'm always making this mistake -.- In your control, do this in the constructor (assuming that you don't have another DataContext): `DataContext = this` and then change the binding to the following: `<Image Source="{Binding IconPath}" />`

Answer (score 1):

The XAML parser is rather clever, when it comes across:

```
<Image Source="Resources\data_store.png"/>
```

It knows that the `Source` property is of `ImageSource` and will use a suitable converter to load the resource specified. If you need to set the image source in code-behind or via a binding you need to do this yourself via a value converter. The following value converter will do the trick:

```
public classImageUriConverter : IValueConverter
{
    publicImageUriConverter()
    {
    }

    public objectConvert(objectvalue, TypetargetType, objectparameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
       Urisource = (Uri)value;
        return newBitmapImage(source);
    }

    public objectConvertBack(objectvalue, TypetargetType, objectparameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw newNotImplementedException();
    }

 }
```

Courtesy of [this blog post](http://vivekdalvi.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/binding-to-image-source/).

Comment: I didnt know it was that clever because If I miswrite "png" with "pgn" for example, I dont have any error but simply got no Image when executing the Project ! Anyway, I don't know how/where I have to use your code, in the codebehind ?